# Count the number of elements that return 1 in a list in one liner

Tags: python

I have a really basic and simple question but for some reason I can't figure it out. I have the following code in python:

```
counter = 0
for el in mylist:
    if self.check_el(el):
        counter += 1
```

I want to make it in one line. Is it something that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, here is one option:

```
counter = sum(1 for el in mylist if self.check_el(el))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(map(lambda el: bool(self.check_el(el)), my_list))
```

Or if you know `check_el` always returns a bool:

```
sum(map(self.check_el, my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
counter = sum(int(self.check_el(el)) for el in mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```py
len(list(filter(self.check_el, mylist)))
```

It filters out all elemenents not fulfilling self.check_el, converts the filter object into a list, and then takes the length of said list. If you want to iterate over the elements, `filter(self.check_el, mylist)` is iterable.

Comment: Given the much simpler approaches that have been posted so far, I'd say this is massive overkill.